# Is it possible to extend a class from another class that only has one constructor with package visibility?

Tags: java

I would like to be able to do the following, keeping in mind that class A and B are in two different packages and I can't modify class A or put class B in the same package of class A:

```
class A{
    A(){
        //stuff
    }
}

class B extends A{
    public B(){
        //stuff
    }
}
```

this code gives "Cannot find simbol: constructor A". Is there any way around that?

Comment: Does A have a public constructor?

Answer (score 3):

In case you can't change class A, you can try to add a new class to the package where A is and extend it to use A, then use B to extend it from the new class.

Comment: the ting i dont understand is, how is it possible to declare A as a private memeber of B when A has default scope(package level scope), can u show an example ??

Answer (score 2):

unless, you make **Class A public**, **NO** is the **ANSWER**, because your **Class A** has **default scope which is only confined to the package level**. to make it **access outside your package mark it as public**

Answer (score 2):

The first thing a class does in its constructor is to call the constructor of its superclass.  As class A doesn't have a public no-arg constructor, you cannot extend B the way you're trying.

If there is a public constructor that takes arguments, you are able to extend it, as long as you call super(arg1, ...); as the first call in your class' constructor:

```
public B()
{
    super(arg1, arg2, argN);
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: your class visiblity still matters if you have a public constructor doesnt it ?

Answer (score 0):

You say you cannot put class `B` in the same package as `A`. But could you have some helper class H in that package? I mean:

```
package a;

class A { ... }

package a;

public class Helper extends A {
    public Helper() { }
}     

package b;

import a.Helper;

class B extends Helper {
    B() { }
}
```

I guess you are dealing with sealed packages so this is not possible, but if it is not the case, then this solution should work.